# OpenGl displaying white texture (not the normal stuff)

Tags: opengl, textures, sdl, render

I feel so stupid... almost immediately after posting this i solved it... Somehow i managed to get the memory address as the value of the texture. I decided to stop sending it around as a reference and instead of a static value (any comments on this?).

The only place i send it back as a reference is after I've converted it from an SDL to texture, maybe it isn't needed here either. Any thought on that would be great!

I'll leave my original post under this if anyone else is having the same problem as me.

---

***SOLVED***

So this is a though one to crack since it works UNTIL i bind the texture. I'll get to it.

At first i load in the image with SDL and convert it to a texture, the convert code is exactly as it is here: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Using_SDL_with_OpenGL (link so i don't type to much). The init code is the same as well.

When the texture is loaded it's saved to a map like so:

Func:

```
GLuint& Loader::loadTex(const string name)
```

Code:

```
//Check if the text is already loaded, if it is return it
map<string, GLuint&>::const_iterator it = m_loadedTextures.find(name);
if(it != m_loadedTextures.end())
{
    return it->second;
}

SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

//Load the file
string loadPath =  m_prePath + name;
surface = lEntity.loadImage(loadPath.c_str(), true);

if(surface == NULL)
{
    //load default texture?
}

//convert the SDL_Surface to a texture
GLuint newTexture = lEntity.glEntity.GetTextureFromSurface(surface);
GLenum h = glGetError();


//free the surface
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

//add to map
m_loadedTextures.insert(pair<string, GLuint&>(name, newTexture));

return newTexture;
```

So after i've recieved the texture i try to draw it like so:

Func:

```
bool OpenGlEntity::renderOpenGl(int x, int y, int w, int h, GLuint& image, SDL_Rect& clip)
```

Code:

```
GLuint texture = image;

// Bind the texture to which subsequent calls refer to
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    //Bottom-left vertex (corner)
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 0 );
    glVertex3f( 100.f, 100.f, 0.0f );

    //Bottom-right vertex (corner)
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 0 );
    glVertex3f( 228.f, 100.f, 0.f );

    //Top-right vertex (corner)
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 1 );
    glVertex3f( 228.f, 228.f, 0.f );

    //Top-left vertex (corner)
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 1 );
    glVertex3f( 100.f, 228.f, 0.f );
glEnd();
```

The thing here is that if i DONT bind the texture when i draw it it'll display the last bound texture (bound in the conversion code i linked). However if i bind the texture i'll instead show a white BG.

I realize that the texture getting bound is probably corrupted somehow, but HOW!? I cant seem to be able to track this down and I've worked with it since yesterday.

I appreciate help super much. Thanks for your time.

Comment: My SDL is pretty rusty, but what happens if you don't free the surface? Do you get the same result?

Comment: I just edited my post, thanks for taking the time to try to understand my problem.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know i could do this! Doing it now!

Edit: I have to wait 2 days until i can do that though :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so stupid... almost immediately after posting this i solved it... Somehow i managed to get the memory address as the value of the texture. I decided to stop sending it around as a reference and instead of a static value (any comments on this?).

The only place i send it back as a reference is after I've converted it from an SDL to texture, maybe it isn't needed here either. Any thought on that would be great!

I'll leave my original post if anyone else is having the same problem as me.